# How can i force TextInput to grow while multiline={false} on react native?

Tags: react-native, keyboard-events, multiline, react-native-textinput

```
<TextInput
  ref={inputRef}
  value={text}
  style={styles.textInput}
  returnKeyType="next"
  placeholder={"placeholder"}
  scrollEnabled={false}
  blurOnSubmit={false}
  onFocus={onFocusInput}
  textAlignVertical="center"
  onContentSizeChange={onChangeContentSizeChange}
  onChangeText={onInputChangeValue}
  onBlur={onInputBlur}
  onKeyPress={onInputKeyPress}
  onSubmitEditing={() => NextScript(id)}
  multiline={false}
  numberOfLines={5}
/>
```

The logic is I want `onSubmitEditing` to take me to next TextInput field and I need the text to wrap one much text is entered. If I enable `multiline` once enter key is pressed it goes to next line before going to the next input and that's what I am trying to avoid.

Is it possible to replace enter key totally with `onSubmitEditing`? Anytime I hit enter it attempts to enter newline before moving to next `TextInput`, so it creates a bad UI where the text is moving up slightly before repositioning then going to next line.

If I set `blurOnSubmit` to true, it stops but keyboard closes on submit.
If I set `multiline` to false it stops but doesn't wrap text.

Comment: Question not clear, Can you add some more of your code or share an image or gif ? Much appreciated

Comment: The problem is my Textinput briefly blinks or goes to the next line before going to next textinput.

    const onInputKeyPress = (
      event: NativeSyntheticEvent<TextInputKeyPressEventData>,
      ) => {
      console.log(event.nativeEvent.key)
      if (event.nativeEvent.key === 'Enter) {
        goToNextInput(id);
      }
    };

The above code in react native, the native enter key always fires before going to next line.

Comment: onKeyPress={(event) => {
    if (event.nativeEvent.key === 'Enter') {
      event.preventDefault(); // Prevent the default behavior (newline)
      NextScript(id); // Move to the next input or handle your logic
    }
  }}

Answer (score 0):

I have created an [example](https://snack.expo.dev/@m.bahl/multiline-textinput-act-on-enter), `onKeyPress`will allow you to focus the next textfield when enter key were hit.

```js
import { Text, SafeAreaView, StyleSheet, TextInput } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <TextInput
        multiline={true}
        placeholder={'PLACEHOLDER'}
        onKeyPress={(e) => {
          if (e.nativeEvent.key == 'Enter') {
            console.log('ENTER');
            //focusNextTextField();
          }
        }}
        style={{ borderColor: '#000000', borderWidth: 1 }}
      />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignContent: 'center',
    padding: 8,
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm also facing the same issues. Later, I found the solution.

Custom Text Input Handling: You'll need a custom logic to handle the text input and its behavior upon pressing the 'Enter' key. Instead of relying on the default behavior of multiline, you'll control the text wrapping and navigation to the next input field programmatically.

Replace Enter Key with onSubmitEditing: To override the default behavior of the 'Enter' key, you can use the onKeyPress event. Detect when the 'Enter' key is pressed and programmatically trigger the onSubmitEditing function.

Maintain Text Wrapping: Since multiline={false} disables automatic text wrapping, you'll need to implement a method to manually handle text wrapping based on the input's content size or character count.

Here's a conceptual example of how you might implement this:

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from 'react';
import { TextInput, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

const CustomTextInput = () => {
  const [text, setText] = useState('');
  const nextInputRef = useRef(null);

  const onInputKeyPress = (e) => {
    if (e.nativeEvent.key === 'Enter') {
      // Replace the Enter key functionality
      // Call the function you would have in onSubmitEditing
      handleEnterKeyPress();
    }
  };

  const handleEnterKeyPress = () => {
    // Logic to navigate to next TextInput
    // Focus the next input field
    if (nextInputRef.current) {
      nextInputRef.current.focus();
    }

    // Additional logic if needed to handle text wrapping
  };

  return (
    <TextInput
      value={text}
      style={styles.textInput}
      onChangeText={setText}
      onKeyPress={onInputKeyPress}
      blurOnSubmit={false} // prevent keyboard from closing
      // other props
    />
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  textInput: {
    // styling for your text input
  },
});

export default CustomTextInput;
```

Comment: The problem is my Textinput briefly blinks or goes to the next line before going to next textinput. const onInputKeyPress = ( event: NativeSyntheticEvent<TextInputKeyPressEventData>, ) => { console.log(event.nativeEvent.key) if (event.nativeEvent.key === 'Enter) { goToNextInput(id); } }; The above code in react native, the native enter key always fires before going to next line

Answer (score 0):

Instead try using this fully customizable TextInput component which I have used for past couple of years ,

```js
import { StyleSheet, Text, TextInput, View, TouchableOpacity, Image } from 'react-native';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { colors, fonts, images } from '../constants';

const InputText = ({
  error,
  labelName,
  labelChild,
  value,
  placeholder,
  onSubmitEditing,
  onChangeText,
  keyboardType,
  secureTextEntry,
  multiline,
  returnKeyType,
  autoFocus,
  placeholderTextColor,
  onBlur,
  errorText,
  inputref,
  inlineImageLeft,
  autoCorrect,
  style,
  onFocus,
  editable,
  maxLength,
  autoCapitalize,
  extraStyle
}) => {
  const [isFocused, setIsFocused] = useState(false);
  const [isPasswordVisible, setIsPasswordVisible] = useState(false);
  const [errorBorderColor, setErrorBorderColor] = useState(colors.lightGreen);

  useEffect(() => {
    setErrorBorderColor(error ? colors.errRed[0] : colors.lightGreen);
  }, [error]);

  const handleTogglePasswordVisibility = () => {
    setIsPasswordVisible(!isPasswordVisible);
  };
  const handleFocus = () => {
    setIsFocused(true);
  };
  const handleBlur = () => {
    setIsFocused(false);
  };
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.label}>{labelName} <Text style={{ color: 'red' }}>{labelChild}</Text></Text>
      <View style={[styles.inputContainer, { borderColor: errorBorderColor }, extraStyle]}>
        <TextInput
          selectionColor={colors.green}
          ref={inputref}
          value={value}
          onChangeText={onChangeText}
          onSubmitEditing={onSubmitEditing}
          autoFocus={autoFocus}
          multiline={multiline}
          secureTextEntry={secureTextEntry && !isPasswordVisible}
          placeholder={placeholder}
          keyboardType={keyboardType}
          returnKeyType={returnKeyType}
          placeholderTextColor={placeholderTextColor}
          style={[styles.input, style]}
          onBlur={onBlur}
          onFocus={handleFocus}
          inlineImageLeft={inlineImageLeft}
          autoCorrect={autoCorrect}
          editable={editable}
          maxLength={maxLength}
          autoCapitalize={autoCapitalize}
        />
        {placeholder === "password" && isFocused && (
          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.iconContainer} onPress={handleTogglePasswordVisibility}>
            <Image
              source={isPasswordVisible ? images.eyeOpen : images.eyeClose}
              style={styles.icon}
            />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        )}
      </View>
      {error && (
        <View style={styles.errorContainer}>
          <Text style={styles.errorText}>{errorText}</Text>
        </View>
      )}
    </View>
  );
};

export default InputText;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    alignItems: 'flex-start',
  },
  inputContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderRadius: 15,
    paddingRight: 10,
    overflow: 'hidden',
  },
  input: {
    flex: 1,
    height: 45,
    fontSize: 18,
    fontFamily: fonts.Regular,
    includeFontPadding: false,
    color: colors.placeholder,
    paddingLeft: 10,
  },
  label: {
    fontSize: 14,
    marginBottom: 10,
    color: colors.black,
    fontWeight: '500',
  },
  iconContainer: {
    padding: 8,
  },
  icon: {
    width: 20,
    height: 20,
  },
  errorContainer: {
    height: 20,
    marginTop: 5,
  },
  errorText: {
    fontSize: 12,
    color: 'red',
    marginTop: 5,
    alignSelf: 'flex-start',
  },
});
```

You can import this and use it in your parent component.